# Exception Handling C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, try-catch

This is maybe a stupid question, but I want to know if my code is programmatically correct.

```
private void Connect()
{
    try
    {
        // I will do something here
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // If something bad happened
        // I want to ignore the problem and continue the execution
        // So, nothing will be placed in the catch block
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine. You can also omit the exception variable name if you won't use it, or even omit the exception type if you want to catch all exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend trying to ignore the "catch" in any exception handling. You should make it a habit to deal with exceptions as they crop up, it's good practice. However, if you need the logic to continue executing, then you can always add the "finally" block, and move on from the exception.

As most have pointed out, ignoring the exception is not recommended. In most cases, even if it doesn't seem like it can't affect anything else, it most likely will cause issues down the road.

I would suggest that you log the exception in some way. At the very least you will get an accurate reading of the failure ratio of the code inside of the "try" block. This might help you later on if you decide to refactor the code.

```
try
{
   //Code here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //Exception handling here
}
finally
{
   //Finish, or continue, execution
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Well, your code accurately depicts your comments. However, it sounds like a very bad idea to continue as if nothing had happened if you've failed to connect. What are you connecting to? What chance is there that you'll *really* be able to keep going successfully? Do you not even want to log the error? Do you really want to catch *all* exceptions rather than just specific ones?

Comment: Connect was just an example, my real problem is that I have two WinForms where the first one needs to put in some variables what has been typed in the second one. So I think it's not very bad to continu the execution. And I don't want to throw something.

Comment: @dotNET: So you're happy continuing **with the wrong data**? Sounds like blowing up is exactly the right thing to do at that point, to be honest...

Comment: I will initialise the Strings with "", so if the user closed the windows without typing something, I will have the right data

Comment: @dotNET: And that's the *only* possible thing that can go wrong? By catching `Exception`, you're basically saying **whatever** happens, I'm going to keep going. It really is almost certainly a *very bad idea*. If you're only interested in the situation where the user closed the windows without typing something, handle *that exact one*.

Answer (score 4):

It is correct but empty catch blocks are such an anti-pattern that this comment block is on the short side. Make very clear that it is empty on purpose.

And since you're not using it, omit the `(Exception ex)` part.

Comment: This what I was looking for. like anti-pattern or something else.

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely correct in your function but could be wrong in your entire applicaiton context. Be aware of a couple of things:

1. Try to never catch generic `Exception`
2. If you want that exception pumps up, so return to the caller, just remove `try/catch` block.
3. If you want to relanch exception make sure to call `throw ex` as in this case you will not loose exception's stack trace.
4. If you want some action is executed always add `finally`, or use the same block to releasae resources you allocated in `try/catch`, if there is any.

I repeat again, in this very localized context it's perfectly fine, but you should see it in entire app context, as exception handling like, for example, fault tollerance have to be acrhitectured, just like UI, Data layer or whatever in yuor sowftare.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In this way we just rethrown exception. See comments for more details.

```
try
{
   // ... 
}
finally
{
  // ... 
}
```

Unit test to demonstrate this:

```
 [Test]
 public void ShouldRethrowExceptionWhenCatchBlockIsNotSpecified()
 {
     Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() =>
         {
             try
             {
                 Debug.WriteLine("1");
                 throw new InvalidOperationException("nothing");
             }
             finally
             {
                 Debug.WriteLine("3");
             }
         });
 }
```

Comment: that doesn't ignore exceptions

Comment: finally has nothing to do wit (not) _handling_ exceptions

Comment: @Ray, Why not? We do nothing in terms of exception handling, application just continue execution by passing execution control into the finally block, in the same time we do not crash on exception

Comment: @sll: No, the exception will be rethrown after the finally block is executed. The exception isn't caught, basically.

Comment: The finally will get executed, but the exception will not be caught. In effect it will be re-thrown after the finally block.

Comment: My bad guys, blame. In this case I should edit my response or delete it completely?

Comment: @sll: I would just add a note to the end of your answer. Other people may have the same misconception and may learn something.

Comment: Edit if you have a better answer, Delete if you want to withdraw it.

Comment: It should be further noted that less exception handling is typically better. Handle your exceptions at the highest level and let everything below that throw it up the tree. I don't think using try/catch as a programming strategy is typically a good idea if nothing else because it makes your code harder to read.